# Crashes with macOS Ventura and external screen

Tags: display, ventura

Unfortunately, I have an issue with my external monitor since upgrading to macOS Ventura on my MBP M1: From time to time the external screen freezes with the MacBook’s screen showing the login screen. An MS Teams call will continue in the background but the only way to resolve the issue is a reboot (potentially losing unsaved data).

Is this a known issue and is there any solution already?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you not log back in? You don't use an old version of Photoshop, by any chance? Only app I've ever seen can force an odd kind of crash/logout.

Comment: what cable are you using

Comment: Thank you, no I cannot log in. I see the beach ball of death.

Comment: I use an HDMI cable now for trouble shooting. Before, it was Display Port.

Comment: Update: error occurs with HDMI, too. However, beach ball of death appears AFTER trying to log in again with my password

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem.

Comment: Do you have an outdated version of Parallels running in the background. Since I turned that off I have not had an issue in a week